# onchange ajax get not work on form method post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, onchange

i'm trying to do onchange event on my form . onchange event use ajax get. but it won't return value.

here's my header asset

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

here's my form

```
<form action="/" method="post" >
    <select name="juz" onchange="juz(this.value)">
        <option value="">-- Pilih --</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <div id="keluar"></div>
</form>
```

and here's script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function juz(val) {
        var hasilSurat = $("#keluar");
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{URL::asset('v1/juz')}}" + '/' + val,
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
        }).done(function(data) {
            if (data.response == 1) {
                hasilSurat.val(data.result);
            } else {
                hasilSurat.val(data.result);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

and from console log

```
test:11 Uncaught TypeError: juz is not a function
at HTMLSelectElement.onchange
```

Comment: Your function name is not matching. It should be same in js as well as in HTML.
in HTML `onchange="jus(this.value)` but in js  ` function juz(val)` 
Take a single name on both location. This code is not able to find function name `jus` so change it to `juz`

Comment: sorry that was my old fault, i have edited + new from console log. it's still debug

Comment: what is console error ?

Comment: here's test:11 Uncaught TypeError: juz is not a function
at HTMLSelectElement.onchange

Comment: may be you have written that js function above the html code. plz right it below html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change select `name` to some other value other than `juz`

```
<select name="juza" onchange="juz(this.value)">
```

Inside `form` tag we are not able to set `name` property value to `onchange` event handler function name.

this code will work, since it's not inside `form`

```
<select name="juz" onchange="juz(this.value)">
        <option value="">-- Pilih --</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
```

this code will not work since `select` is inside form,

```
<form action="/" method="post" >
    <select name="juz" onchange="juz(this.value)">
        <option value="">-- Pilih --</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <div id="keluar"></div>
</form>
```

Not sure about the reason, I will try update it.

Comment: it works ! since i rename "name" attributes to another ! thankyou !!